# Scala Cats EitherT and foreach

Tags: scala, scala-cats, either

I am trying to achieve something like the following code

```
def getUsers: EitherT[Future, String, Response] = {
  for {
    users <- EitherT(userRepository.findAll) // this method would retrieve a Future[Either[String, Seq[User]]]
    user <- users
    friends <- EitherT(userRepository.findFriends(user.id))
  } yield new Response(user, friends)
}
```

I understand that this is not possible, because `EitherT` does not manage `foreach`.

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String, email: String)

case class Response(user: User, friends: Seq[User])
```

Which would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: @erip thank you for reading, I updated the question trying to be explain my idea.

Comment: `user <- users` isn't doing anything. Even if it did, you'd be creating a list of friends for every user. It seems like your function only wants to return a reponse _per user_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are finding all users, you will have multiple users with their respective friends, so I modified your return value to return a `List` of `Response`s instead. Then perhaps you want to do something like this:

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.Future

def getUsers: EitherT[Future, String, List[Response]] = {
  EitherT(userRepository.findAll).flatMap { users =>
    users.toList.traverse(user => EitherT(userRepository.findFriends(user.id)).map(Response(user, _)))
  }
}
```

Make sure you have an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope or import `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`.

Comment: I was about to add the same answer. Nice one.

Comment: @Lasf thank you for your answer. I was trying something like that, but what I needed was the traverse. I ended up doing a for yield and nesting another for yield with filters.

Comment: @agusgambina for what it's worth, `traverse` is essentially a `map` followed by a `sequence`.